# How to update hierarchical index after drop in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I set up my DataFrame like so:

```
cols = ['molecule_id', 'atom_id', 'atom_type', 'x', 'y', 'z']
data = pd.DataFrame()\
         .from_dict(data_dict, orient='index', columns=cols)\
         .set_index(['molceule_id', 'atom_id'])
print(data.head(8))
```

Here `data_dict: dict[str, list]`
It results in:

```
                    atom_type         x         y         z
molecule_id atom_id
0           0               C -2.893477 -2.893477 -2.893477
            1               S -3.293477 -2.893477 -2.893477
1           0               C -2.893477 -1.736086 -1.736086
            1               S -3.293477 -1.736086 -1.736086
2           0               C -1.736086 -2.893477 -1.736086
            1               S -2.136086 -2.893477 -1.736086
3           0               C -1.736086 -1.736086 -2.893477
            1               S -2.136086 -1.736086 -2.893477
```

Later in the code, I need to remove a molecule (say #1) from this frame, thus I do:

```
data.drop(labels=1, level='molecule_id', axis=0, inplace=True)
```

```
                    atom_type         x         y         z
molecule_id atom_id
0           0               C -1.736086 -2.893477 -1.736086
            1               S -2.136086 -2.893477 -1.736086
2           0               C -2.893477 -2.893477 -2.893477
            1               S -3.293477 -2.893477 -2.893477
3           0               C -2.893477 -1.736086 -1.736086
            1               S -3.293477 -1.736086 -1.736086
4           0               C -1.736086 -2.893477  0.578695
            1               S -2.136086 -2.893477  0.578695
```

At this point, I would want to adjust 'molecule_id' index to achieve the desired output:

```
                    atom_type         x         y         z
molecule_id atom_id
0           0               C -1.736086 -2.893477 -1.736086
            1               S -2.136086 -2.893477 -1.736086
1           0               C -2.893477 -2.893477 -2.893477
            1               S -3.293477 -2.893477 -2.893477
2           0               C -2.893477 -1.736086 -1.736086
            1               S -3.293477 -1.736086 -1.736086
3           0               C -1.736086 -2.893477  0.578695
            1               S -2.136086 -2.893477  0.578695
```

Upon setting an index Pandas seem to create FrozenList, thus I could not do something like:

```
data.index.levels[0] = new_id_level
```

The solution I have in mind is to rebuild MultiIndex from scratch and apply to the DataFrame with `set_index()`:

```
atoms_per_molecule = 2
num_molecules = len(data)//atoms_per_molecule
molecule_id = np.repeat(range(num_molecules), atoms_per_molecule)
atom_id = np.tile(range(atoms_per_molecule), num_molecules)
tuples = list(zip(molecule_id, atom_id))
names = ['molecule_id', 'atom_id']
multi_id = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=names)
data.set_index(multi_id, inplace=True)
```

It works well but seems unreasonably complicated considering the number of drops I plan to perform.

Therefore, I am wondering if there are any other and more efficient ways to do so?
P.S: Maybe it is possible to create some kind of resettable index using a given pattern?

Comment: Does [set_levels](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html) fit your use case?

Comment: @sammywemmy Thank you, that is exactly what I needed! I should read docs more thoroughly :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    'b': [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    'col_1': [3, 14, 15, 92, 65, 35, 89, 79],
    'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
})
data = data.set_index(['a', 'b'])
data = data.drop(labels=1, level='a', axis=0, inplace=False)
print(data)
```

This gives:

```
     col_1 col_2
a b             
0 0      3     a
  1     14     b
  2     15     c
2 0     65     e
  1     35     f
3 0     89     g
  1     79     h
```

Modify index:

```
data.index = data.index.remove_unused_levels()
n = data.index.get_level_values(0).nunique()
data.index = data.index.set_levels(range(n), level=0)
```

When you drop rows from a dataframe, this does not change the underlying index. The first line modifies the index removing index levels that are no longer used in the dataframe. The second line counts the number of distinct values in the level 0 of the new index. Finally, the third line replaces level 0 values with consecutive integers.

The resulting dataframe looks as follows:

```
     col_1 col_2
a b             
0 0      3     a
  1     14     b
  2     15     c
1 0     65     e
  1     35     f
2 0     89     g
  1     79     h
```

Comment: Thank you @bb1 for the detailed explanation! It is much more concise than my way of rebuilding indices. Though, it is a bit frustrating for me how Pandas' naming utilizes the word 'levels' (now that I realize `.remove_unused_levels()` may also be interpreted somewhat as `.remove_unused_level_values()`)